# call json web api nopcommerce

Tags: json, web-services, asp.net-web-api, nopcommerce

Hi I am new for nopcommerce 3.5. I need to write a restful web service api to third party(for eg **mobile**) access the service. I know that we can access through **Nop.Plugin.Misc.WebServices** . I had enable the service from administrator site.

But now is my question. How can i call the web service for eg **GetPaymentMethod** , **product list** and etc

And if I want to write my custom web service by using web api. what is step to create? I cant find any documentation about the web service. Please guide me some example

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a really quick start in writing a web service in NopCommerce, you can follow the MVC architecture and:

- Create an Action method inside a Controller that you find appropriate for your purpose. For example, if you want access to a product list, you might create an Action inside CatalogController that follows the logic of the existing ProductList action.
- Set up a Route in RouteProvider.cs to point to the Action you created. Based on this route you can deduce the URL of your service.
- Do the processing that you need inside the Action. If this Action/service is to be called with parameters (in query string format: `param=value&param2=value2`), you can just put these parameters in the Action's header:
  `public ActionResult QuickService(int param, string param2) { ...` and .NET will take care of having them initialized.
- Store results in an object (can also be an anonymous object) and at the end of your action, return it as Json: `return Json(resultsObject);` Again, ASP.NET takes care of the JSON serialization and automatically sets the `Content-Type` HTTP response header to "application/json".
- You can consume the service calling the URL that corresponds to the route of your Action.

If you want users to be able to log in, by using the above method, it gets a little bit trickier. You need the webservice client to be able to accept and send cookies, as well as make appropriate services for Login, Logout, Register,...

However, in this case, you might be better off with a mobile version of the site.

Final note: If you don't want to alter base NopCommerce code, you can apply the steps above to a plugin. The majority of NopCommerce plugins follow the MVC architecture, so you can apply the steps above.